# Solr search FIND_IN_SET like MySQL

Tags: solr, solr4

In solr indexed some data, for example:

```
Fieldname="29655,2542,21542", 
Fieldname="2542"
```

which gets indexed successfully.
But I need the data which is available as `2542`.

In the above example, two results should be displayed but I only get the second value, not both.

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: please tell us, which kind of index you are using, how does your query look like. This could just be a simple spelling mistake...

Comment: Share the schema.xml or the fieldtype used for the field...

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the analysis chain for the field. You can use a `solr.PatternTokenizerFactory` to split the content into separate tokens by `,`.

```
<fieldType name="commadelimited" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="," />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

You'll then reference this fieldtype when defining the field:

```
<field name="fieldname" type="commadelimited" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```